# Magento 2: How to Extend \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems.php class for adding an extra function?

Tags: php, email, templates, magento2

I want to extend the \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems.php class so I can add an extra function instead of putting in the core file. (which works btw)

```
<preference for="\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems"
                type="MyModule\MyVendor\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems" />
```

Then extend the class like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\MyVendor\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Order\Email\Items;


class DefaultItems extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems
{


    /**
     * DefaultItems constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        die('Class extended');

    }
}
```

When I make a function getSku() my IDE (PHPstorm) shows that it will be overridden like it supposed to. When sending an invoice email through the backend it will show me the die in the constructor.

When deleting the constructor (or the die) I am getting the following error message:

```
Unknown template engine type ".
```

So what am i missing here, any ideas?